# FMElfinderBundle 5 - how to set temp folder for upload

Tags: symfony, elfinder

I am using FMElfinderBundle v.5 (for some reasons I cannot use latest version) with Symfony 2.8.12. I followed documentation and it worked fine, until there was request to allow upload large files (up to 20MB). I changed upload_max_size parameter to 20M and it was ok, but during upload files are split to 2MB chunks and elfinder tries to store them in temp directory. Problem is, that it has no access there. It does not read settings from virtual host definition, it always uses system temp folder.

Reading documentation I have found that there can be used two parameters for configuring elfinder temp dir - `upload_temp_path` and `common_temp_path`. But i didn't have luck with setting them. Every time I run in PHPStorm console command s cache: `clear --no-warmup` I get InvalidConfigurationException.

I tried to put parameters somewhere else in config structure under fm_elfinder key, but still the same exception.

This is my configuration in `config.yml`:

```
    fm_elfinder:
        instances:
            default:
                locale: %locale%
                editor: ckeditor
                fullscreen: true
                theme: smoothness
                include_assets: true
                relative_path: false
                connector:
                    roots:
                        uploads:
                            driver: LocalFileSystem
                            path: uploads
                            upload_max_size: 20M
```

Anyone please can help me, how to set temp dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have found solution. It is necessary to make yoour own custom configuration reader and replace the original one. Configuration class must implement ElFinderConfigurationProviderInterface. See [https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/advanced-configuration.md#custom-configuration-provider][1] for more details.

Comment: Could you care to share your result for the ElfinderConfigurator class ? I'm struggling for having a valid option returned by it. Thank you

Comment: Works smoothly - i put some datails in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, some detailed info:

I took ElFinderConfigurationReader from ElFinder bundle and saved it into my project under name ElFinderConfigurationCustomReader. Then this class i defined as a service:

```
service.custom_fm_elfinder.configurator:
    class: CSBN\SVJBundle\Component\ElFinder\ElFinderConfigurationCustomReader
    arguments: ['%fm_elfinder%', '@request_stack', '@service_container', '%elfinder_temporary_path%']
```

variable elfinder_temporary_path is set in parameters.yml.

in config.yml i set my own configuration reader:

```
fm_elfinder:
configuration_provider: service.custom_fm_elfinder.configurator
```

And in my newly created file ElFinderConfigurationCustomReader i just in method getConfiguration added one row:

```
$options['uploadTempPath'] = $this->temporaryPath;
```

which is taken from service parameters in constructor.

Hope this helps you.

Edit: full function copy:

```
/**
 * @param $instance
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getConfiguration($instance)
{
    $request                = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $efParameters           = $this->parameters;
    $parameters             = $efParameters['instances'][$instance];
    $options                = array();
    $options['corsSupport'] = $parameters['cors_support'];
    $options['debug']       = $parameters['connector']['debug'];
    $options['bind']        = $parameters['connector']['binds'];
    $options['plugins']     = $parameters['connector']['plugins'];
    $options['uploadTempPath'] = $this->temporaryPath;
    $options['roots']       = array();

    foreach ($parameters['connector']['roots'] as $parameter) {
        $path       = $parameter['path'];
        $homeFolder = $request->attributes->get('homeFolder');
        if ($homeFolder !== '') {
            $homeFolder = '/'.$homeFolder.'/';
        }

        $driver = $this->container->has($parameter['driver']) ? $this->container->get($parameter['driver']) : null;

        $driverOptions = array(
            'driver'            => $parameter['driver'],
            'service'           => $driver,
            'glideURL'          => $parameter['glide_url'],
            'glideKey'          => $parameter['glide_key'],
            'plugin'            => $parameter['plugins'],
            'path'              => $path.$homeFolder, //removed slash for Flysystem compatibility
            'startPath'         => $parameter['start_path'],
            'URL'               => $this->getURL($parameter, $request, $homeFolder, $path),
            'alias'             => $parameter['alias'],
            'mimeDetect'        => $parameter['mime_detect'],
            'mimefile'          => $parameter['mimefile'],
            'imgLib'            => $parameter['img_lib'],
            'tmbPath'           => $parameter['tmb_path'],
            'tmbPathMode'       => $parameter['tmb_path_mode'],
            'tmbUrl'            => $parameter['tmb_url'],
            'tmbSize'           => $parameter['tmb_size'],
            'tmbCrop'           => $parameter['tmb_crop'],
            'tmbBgColor'        => $parameter['tmb_bg_color'],
            'copyOverwrite'     => $parameter['copy_overwrite'],
            'copyJoin'          => $parameter['copy_join'],
            'copyFrom'          => $parameter['copy_from'],
            'copyTo'            => $parameter['copy_to'],
            'uploadOverwrite'   => $parameter['upload_overwrite'],
            'uploadAllow'       => $parameter['upload_allow'],
            'uploadDeny'        => $parameter['upload_deny'],
            'uploadMaxSize'     => $parameter['upload_max_size'],
            'defaults'          => $parameter['defaults'],
            'attributes'        => $parameter['attributes'],
            'acceptedName'      => $parameter['accepted_name'],
            'disabled'          => $parameter['disabled_commands'],
            'treeDeep'          => $parameter['tree_deep'],
            'checkSubfolders'   => $parameter['check_subfolders'],
            'separator'         => $parameter['separator'],
            'timeFormat'        => $parameter['time_format'],
            'archiveMimes'      => $parameter['archive_mimes'],
            'archivers'         => $parameter['archivers'],
        );

        if ($parameter['volume_id'] > 0) {
            $driverOptions['id'] = $parameter['volume_id'];
        }

        if (!$parameter['show_hidden']) {
            $driverOptions['accessControl'] = array($this, 'access');
        };

        $options['roots'][] = array_merge($driverOptions, $this->configureDriver($parameter));
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: thanks. it's just the ElFinderConfigurationCustomReader that bothers me : do you have `public function getConfiguration($instance) {$options['uploadTempPath'] = $this->temporaryPath; ... return $options;}` ? Could you put the whole getConfiguration() method ? Thanks you again

Comment: added to previous post

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a last thing. what is your `$this->getURL($parameter, $request, $homeFolder, $path),` method like : how do you construct your url ? and also `$this->configureDriver($parameter)` My problem is that my images are not displayed, just the elfinder icon. They are present, uploaded correctly, but i can't insert them. I think this is an url /path problem. That's why i'm asking for a working solution. Sorry if i pollute your topic :'(

Comment: finally with your code i manage to make it work. Thanks a million.